# How to render array of elements as <Dialog> in a <List>

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, material-ui

I'm building a component, `<ElementList>` that receives an array of elements in the props and builds a `<List>` where each `<ListItem>` is a element of array. 
I'm passing the `<ListItem>` a separate component called `<ElementShow>`, which wraps a material-ui `<Dialog>` component.
When a `<ListItem>` is clicked, it should open the `<Dialog>` for the specific `<ElementShow>` component.

Currently, when I click on any of the `<ListItem>`'s it opens the `<Dialog>` for the last element of the array, regardless of which `<ListItem>` I click.

Here's the code for reference:

ElementList.js

```
import React from 'react'
import {List, ListItem} from 'material-ui/List'
import Subheader from 'material-ui/Subheader'
import ElementShow from './ElementShow'

class ElementList extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      dialogOpen: false
    }
  }

  handleOpen = () => {
    this.setState({dialogOpen: true})
  }

  handleClose = () => {
    this.setState({dialogOpen: false})
  }

  renderElements () {
    const {elements} = this.props
    if (elements.length < 1) {
      return (
        <ListItem
          key='empty_element'
          primaryText='No Elements Yet'
        />
      )
    } else {
      return elements.map(element => {
        return (
          <ListItem
            key={element._id}
            primaryText={element.name}
            onClick={this.handleOpen}
          >
            <ElementShow
              dialogOpen={this.state.dialogOpen}
              handleClose={this.handleClose} element={element} />
          </ListItem>
        )
      })
    }
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <List className='box'>
        <Subheader>Elements</Subheader>
        {this.renderElements()}
      </List>
    )
  }
}
export default ElementList
```

ElementShow.js

```
import React from 'react'
import Dialog from 'material-ui/Dialog'

class ElementShow extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      open: props.dialogOpen
    }
  }

  render () {
    const { element, handleClose } = this.props
    return (
      <Dialog
        title={element.name}
        modal={false}
        open={this.props.dialogOpen}
        onRequestClose={handleClose}>
        {element}
      </Dialog>
    )
  }
}

export default ElementShow
```

I think I need to link the dialog state to the specific character, but I haven't been able to find a method that works yet.

Any help/tips are appreciated!

Comment: Is it not possible to do the `onRequestClose` inside ElementShow instead? Why does the parent need to pass down a `handleClose`?

Comment: I guess the parent doesn't need to pass down `handleClose`. The issue is that I need to attach an dialogOpen state to each element and be able to change the value of it from the parent component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, one issue you have is that `this.state` is the parent component's state, not specific to each child - so when you write

```
elements.map((element) => {
    ...
    <ElementShow dialoagOpen={ this.state.dialogOpen } />
})
```

it will effect all elements.

What I would do is something like

```
class ElementList {
    onClickElement = (element) => {
        this.setState({
            dialogOpen: true,
            selectedElement: element
        });
    }

    render() {
        const mElements = elements.map((element) => {
            /* I would suggest using a partial here, as opposed to what I've written */
            return <ListItem onClick={ () => { this.onClickElement(element) } } />
        });

        const { selectedElement } = this.state;

        return (
            <div>
                <List className='box'>
                    <Subheader>Elements</Subheader>
                    { mElements } 
                </List>

                { selectedElement && (
                    <Dialog
                        title={ selectedElement.name }
                        modal={ false}
                        open={ this.state.dialogOpen }
                        element={ selectedElement }
                        onRequestClose={ this.handleClose }
                    >
                        { selectedElement }
                    </Dialog>
                ) }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I think this will accomplish what you want. When you want to hide the dialog, you set `this.state.dialogOpen` to `false` and clear `this.state.selectedElement`.

Comment: Thank you!! This works as intended. I can pass the `<ElementShow>` component instead of the dialog inside the `selectedElement &&` block.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have individual state (true or false) for each dialog rendered.

Pass the index of each element to your `handleOpen` and `handleClose` functions and use that to toggle the correct state.

```
return elements.map((element, index) => {
        return (
          <ListItem
            key={element._id}
            primaryText={element.name}
            onClick={() => this.handleOpen(index)}
          >
            <ElementShow
              dialogOpen={this.state.dialogOpen[index]}
              handleClose={this.handleClose(index)} element={element} />
          </ListItem>
        )
      })
```

Next, setup your state as an array equal to the number of elements and also initialize the first dialog as open. Include the index in your open/close functions to access parts of the array.

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      dialogOpen: props.element.map((element, index) => {
        return index === 0 ? true : false;
      }
    }
  }

  handleOpen = (index) => {
    this.setState({ dialogOpen[index]: true })
  }

  handleClose = (index) => {
    this.setState({ dialogOpen[index]: false })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using hooks here is my solution:

```
  const [openDialog, setDialogOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const [selectedElement, setSelectedElement] = React.useState();

  const handleDialogOpen = (element) => {
    setDialogOpen(true);
    setSelectedElement(element);
  };
  return (
    {elements.map((e) => (
     ...
     <CardActionArea onClick={() => handleDialogOpen(e)}>
     ...
     {selectedElement && (
        <EditDialog
         selectedElement={selectedElement}
         openDialog={openDialog}
         setOpenDialog={setDialogOpen}
         />
      )}
    ))}
  )
```